# How to un-Bootstrap Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Typically an Angular application is defined by `ng-app="someModule"` as an attribute in a `<html> <body>` or `<div>` tag. We're instead, manually "bootstrapping" it from a function inside the head section.

For example, index.html file:

```
function manualBootstrap() {
  angular.element('document').ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['someModule']);
  });
}
manualBootstrap();
```

In our app.js file we define:

```
angular.module('someModule', [
  'ngRoute',
  'RestApi',
  ...
  'someModule.homepage',
  'someModule.contact'
])
```

Is the correct way to "un" bootstrap angular - just remove the function and use the ng-app directive somewhere on the index.html file? Or is there more to this?

Reason: Protractor doesn't support manually bootstrapped angular.

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript way to _un-bootstrap_ the app?  Or just how you would go about it without the boostrapping process in the first place?

Comment: I would like to know how to properly remove the 'bootstrapped' aspects and return to the intended angular approach. I'm not necessarily looking for a dynamic javascript way of doing this.

Comment: It would be a bad move, but the reason to do this to because of Protractor makes it even worse. I would suggest to solve it with angular.bootstrap, check this thread https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/66 for all possible solutions.

Comment: knowing nothing about Protractor, I would defer to @estus's comment.  However, you can just use the `ng-app="appName"` attribute that aligns with your entry module's name `angular.module( 'appName', [])`

Comment: Check for asynchronous module loaders. Those can cause a problem if you auto-bootstrap. Make sure that everything that loads asynchronously is done before loading `angular.js` and its modules.